# $X$ equipped with discrete topology $\implies$ only connected sets of $X$ are of the form $\{ x \} $ for $x \in X$

Tags: calculus, general-topology

So, Im trying to show that only the singletons in a set $X$ with discrete topology are connected sets. Pick arbitrary $\{ x \} \subset X$. And suppose $\{ x \} = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are open relative to $X$ and they are nonempty and disjoint. But, since they are non-empty, $A \cup B$ must contain at least two points, therefore we have a contradiction.

Is this solution correct? Can someone give me some feedback? thanks

Improved Solution: Take any $C \subseteq X$. Suppose $C$ is connected. We show $C$ is a singleton. Since $C$ is connected, then $C$ cannot be written as a disjoint union of elements $A$ and $B$ of $\mathcal{T}_X$. In other words, if $C = A \cup B \implies C = A $ or $C = B$. Say $C$ contains more than one element. Since $C \in \mathcal{T}_X$, then $C$ can be written as a union of elements in the basis of $X$, say $C = \bigcup N_x$. We know $N_x$, the neighborhoods, are open by definition. If the $N_x$ are disjoint, then we are done. Otherwise, If $C = A$, then we will end up having $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$ which is a contradiction. Therefore, $C$ must be a singleton.

Comment: Well you've shown that every singleton set is connected. Suppose $U\subset X$ has more than one point. Can you show it's disconnected?

Comment: You’ve shown (correctly) that each singleton is connected; this is true (by the same argument) in all spaces. You haven’t yet done the important part, which is to show that if $X$ is discrete, and $C\subseteq X$ is connected, then $C$ is a singleton.

Comment: I have improved my solution now. Does it look better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't correct--you've proved that singletons are connected. You need to show that if $A\subseteq X$ has the property that for any two disjoint, relatively open $U,V\subseteq A$ with $A=U\cup V$ we must have one of $A=U$ or $A=V,$ then $A$ is a singleton or is the empty set.

As a hint: *every* subset of $X$ is open, so relatively open and open are the same thing. If $A$ has more than one element, can you rewrite it as a disjoint union of two non-empty subsets (which will be open by discreteness)?

Comment: I have improved my solution now, what do you think?

Comment: A bit cumbersome. Take any $x\in C$ and put $A=\{x\}$. What should we make $B$ to get the contradiction?

Comment: $ B = C \setminus \{ x \} $ ?

Comment: Bingo! And since we assumed that $C$ had more than one element, it follows that neither $A$ nor $B$ is equal to $C$.

Comment: However, I have one silly queston: Are we allowed to make $A$ and $B$ any set we want?

Comment: Absolutely! That's the nice thing (in this case) about the discrete topology: every set is open.

Answer (score 0):

You are proving that singletons are connected, not that singletons are the *only* connected sets. In fact, by your argument, singletons are connected in any topology, so I'd suggest proving that if an open set in a discrete space has more than one element, it is disconnected.